# Is there a way to not right NULL or list all values when dealing with auto_increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, insert-into

Hello guys I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  cod int(3) auto_increment,
  text varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY(cod));
```

I would like to know how can if there is a way to insert into like this

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('test');
```

and get this

```
+-----+------+
| cod | text |
+-----+------+
|   1 | test |
+-----+------+
```

just completely ignoring the cod column since it's auto_incrementing, I know you can declare what values you're planning to insert or just pass null, but I would like to know if there is a way apart from those two ways

Comment: INSERT INTO test(text) VALUES ('test');   this can be use, but if your table having two column and without specifying the column list you can't skip

Comment: You can insert it that way too (INSERT INTO test VALUES ('test');) is it not working for you?

Comment: Note that the little (3) in parentheses is pretty much meaningless

Comment: You want the engine to read your mind? ;-)

Comment: @KKK nice nickname, I know you can do it like that, I just wanted to make sure that you can't do it in other way

Comment: @AlexGS no, I have this error "ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for pointing it out, I'll keep it in mind in other projects!

Answer (score 1):

Specify a column list in the INSERT statement...

```
INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES ('test')
                 ^^^^^^
```

Any columns omitted from the column list will have a default value assigned. In the case of a column with no default value assigned, the default is NULL. This would be equivalent to

```
INSERT INTO test (text, cod) VALUES ('test', NULL)
                      ^^^^^                ^^^^^^
```

Note that the first value in the values list goes to the first column in the column list, the second value to the second column, etc.

If the column list is omitted, then the default column list is *all* of the columns defined in the table, in the same order that they are defined in the table. So we could also write:

```
INSERT INTO test (cod, text) VALUES (NULL, 'test')
```

So it's only the special case where we are supplying values for *every* column, and the values are supplied in the *same order* as the columns are defined in the table, where we can omit the column list.

Best practice is to always supply a column list, and not rely on the order of columns in the table. This makes it easier on the future reader to figure out which values are being assigned to which columns, without having to lookup the table definition. This also prevents the INSERT statement from "breaking" when a new column is a added to the table, or when the columns are reordered.